# How much device storage space is required for Firebase (Firestore)?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I received a crash report from one user of my app that described an error where the user didn't have enough space on their device to create the database.

> Failed to open DB: Error Domain=FIRFirestoreErrorDomain Code=13
>   "Failed to create database main at path
>   /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7560B07B-4F8E-47B7-BC36-2831C6CCBA23/Documents/firestore/__FIRAPP_DEFAULT/{*redacted*}/main"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to create database main at
>   path
>   /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7560B07B-4F8E-47B7-BC36-2831C6CCBA23/Documents/firestore/__FIRAPP_DEFAULT/{*redacted*}/main,
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=IO error:
>   /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7560B07B-4F8E-47B7-BC36-2831C6CCBA23/Documents/firestore/__FIRAPP_DEFAULT/{*redacted*}/main/000057.ldb:
>   **No space left on device**}

To solve this, I'd like to check how much free space the user has on their device before configuring Firebase, but in order to make this comparison to see if they have enough space, I'd need to know how much space Firebase requires on a device, and I can't seem to find this information in any Firebase documentation.

Any info on this would be appreciated!

Comment: if you store the cache locally it depends on the your data

Comment: Would there be a way to check how much data that is before configuring Firebase? Seems like I'm caught in a catch 22.

Comment: Performing this check once isn't really going to help the situation.  The user is just going to keep running out of space as all their different apps continue to write data on the device.  The user really just need to clean up their device.  Uninstall unused apps, delete pictures and music, that sort of thing.

Comment: `getAvailableBlocksLong`

public long getAvailableBlocksLong ()
The number of blocks that are free on the file system and available to applications. This corresponds to the Unix statvfs.f_bavail field.

Comment: I did realize that I can wrap FirebaseApp.configure() in a try catch. The documentation for FirebaseApp.configure() states: "Raises an exception if any configuration step fails", so that'll allow me to check the error and display a message to the user if they're out of space. This will actually perfectly solve my problem, as all I wanted to do is display a message to the user that they need to make space to use the app if configuring Firebase fails due to storage limitations.

Comment: Never mind, despite FirebaseApp.configure() stating that it raises an exception, because it doesn't throw, this exception can't be caught. @DougStevenson is right anyways, as a one-time check won't solve the issue of space. Shame there isn't any sort of notification that gets posted when the user is close to running out of space that I could listen to. Looks like I'll just have to hope that users who max out their space clean out their device.

Comment: @DougStevenson That sounds like (the basis for) a good answer. Feel like writing it up?